# Showing data from multiple tables in a particular format

Tags: sql, reporting-services

This is the detailed issue: I have several tables that have some columns in common (the `TOS` column) so what I need to do is to see the data diplayed in the following format:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8oDBm.png)

```
    TOS         Percentage
                100.00%
default (DSCP 0)61.74%
af33 (DSCP 30)  15.44%
af31 (DSCP 26)  13.85%
af11 (DSCP 10)  4.63%
ef (DSCP 46)    3.72%
cs6 (DSCP 48)   0.23%
cs4 (DSCP 32)   0.20%
cs3 (DSCP 24)   0.11%
af21 (DSCP 18)  0.05%
af41 (DSCP 34)  0.03%
                0.02%
```

and this is the data from Table B:

```
    TOS        Percentage
                100.00%
default (DSCP 0)61.37%
af11 (DSCP 10)  15.22%
af33 (DSCP 30)  11.49%
af31 (DSCP 26)  8.86%
ef (DSCP 46)    1.91%
af41 (DSCP 34)  0.70%
cs4 (DSCP 32)   0.15%
af12 (DSCP 12)  0.12%
cs3 (DSCP 24)   0.06%
af21 (DSCP 18)  0.05%
                0.07%
```

What I need is the data to be formatted as per the image above. I came up with the following query but it seems to dupplicate a LOT of the data:

```
SELECT       
    SiteA.TOS AS RSite A,
    SiteA.Percentage, 
    SiteB.TOS AS Site B, 
    SiteB.Percentage 
FROM            
    SiteA 
CROSS JOIN
    SiteB
```

If I have not explained myself propperly please let me know and also if the question has not been posted properly let me know as well as I am totally new to stackoverflow!

Comment: can somebody tell me how to edit this question that i have just posted as i forgot to add some more details!

Comment: Click on the 'edit' at the bottom of the question, near the tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you meant to use an INNER JOIN :

```
SELECT SiteA.TOS AS RSite A,
       SiteA.Percentage, 
       SiteB.Percentage 
FROM  SiteA 
INNER JOIN  SiteB
 ON(SiteA.TOS = SiteB.TOS)
```

Or with a left join in case there can be data on only one of the tables

```
SELECT SiteA.TOS AS RSite A,
       SiteA.Percentage, 
       SiteB.Percentage 
FROM  SiteA 
LEFT JOIN  SiteB
 ON(SiteA.TOS = SiteB.TOS)
```

Comment: Thanks for that sagi, i just now need to figure out how to present the data in the format specified on the image file attached to this question

Comment: @RaulGonzales You can open another post, post all the tables structures(which you didn't do now) and say exactly what you want, we'll help you achieve it.